# mod_rewrite forward shortend URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am looking for a way to create a short URL path for a longer URL on my page

the long url is: domain.com/tagcloud/user.html?t=1234ABCD

i would like to offer a short version of the URL to easy access it:

domain.com/t/1234ABCD

I tried a few examples but I just don't get it how I could forward these rules.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/t/$ /tagcloud/user.html?t=$1 [L]
```

I am also using MODX so they already use rules.

in addition my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Always use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I must keep the code snippets above in my htaccess file. The first one simply forwards http://domain.com requests to www.domain.com

**The friendly URLs part** is needed to translate the internal IDs of my CMS with the alias of the URL. This feature must remain because the entire site cannot be influencted by the changes I try to make in htaccess...

I simply would like to add a listener that only if the URL matches www.domain.com/t/abcd1234

Therefore I need something that identifies the www.domain.com/t/ URL

your help is much appreciated

Comment: What is the RewriteCond for the tagcloud rule?

Comment: Gereon, I tried to write this rule, but I failed. So far there is no rule for it. I just would like to add a rule in my current htaccess file that complements it and in case the "trigger" shortendURL is entered it gets forwarded to the actual long URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/t/.*
RewriteRule ^t/(.*)$ /tagcloud/user.html?t=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. The way you coded it seems right, but I am not a mod rewrite expert... it does not work unfortunately. If I enter it the CMS referes to the sitemap of the page with automatically shows up if a document is not found with a given alias... so I guess the rule maybe can not overpower the other rule?

Comment: That depends on what other rules in what order are evaluated. Is what you pasted above your complete .htaccess? Try moving the new rules above the rule that redirects to index.php

Comment: I edited my comment and added my entire htacess file. I tried putting your code snippet above "The friendly URLs part". Bit it has no effect. It still routes me to the CMS internal not found page.

Comment: my bad, there was an extra / in my original answer, I've updated the RewriteRule

Comment: fantastic Gereon. You nailed it. It works. Thank you very much.